# Show documentation pages in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where I want to display some documentation pages in the GUI. The following app works well for packages that were installed as source packages, i.e. with

```
install.packages(packagename, type = "source")
```

However, for binary packages I am not able to extract the same `html` files from the package directory. Having access to `.Rd` files would be enough due to `tools::Rd2HTML`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(shiny)

# get a character vector containing all source packages or packages
# containing more than two files in pkgdir/html
pkgs <- rownames(installed.packages())
ndoc <- vapply(pkgs, function(pkg){
  length(list.files(system.file("html", package = pkg)))}, 0)
src_pkgs <- pkgs[ndoc > 2]

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("package", "select package", src_pkgs),
  uiOutput("choose_topic"),
  wellPanel(uiOutput("documentation"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$choose_topic <- renderUI({
    choices <- list.files(system.file("html", package = input$package))
    selectInput("topic", "select topic", choices)
  })

  output$documentation <- renderUI({
    includeHTML(
      system.file(paste0("html/", req(input$topic)), package = input$package)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Edit

I just came up with an alternative way of showing the man pages using `tools::startDynamicHelp`. This works with all packages and even enables links to other man pages. However, this approch doesn't work with `shiny-server` since it uses the loopback interface (`127.0.0.1`).

```
library(shiny)

pkgs <- rownames(installed.packages())

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("package", "select package", pkgs),
    uiOutput("choose_topic")
  ),
  mainPanel(uiOutput("documentation"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  port <-  tools::startDynamicHelp(NA)
  home <- paste0("http://127.0.0.1:", port)

  output$choose_topic <- renderUI({
    choices <- unique(readRDS(system.file("help/aliases.rds", package = input$package)))
    selectInput("topic", "select topic", choices)
  })

  output$documentation <- renderUI({
    url <- paste0(home, "/library/", input$package, "/html/", input$topic,".html")
    tags$iframe(src = url, width = "100%", height = "900px")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a way to make use of the files in `packagedir/help` thanks to [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/build-static-html-help-pages-for-r-packages/) on Rbloggers.

This version fetches the contents of the Rd-database (`RdDB`) file and then builts a `HTML` version of the documentation file in the `tmp` folder. It disables all links, which is what I want actually. It also works on `shiny-server`.

```
library(shiny)
library(tools)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("package", "select package", .packages(all.available = TRUE)),
    uiOutput("choose_topic")
  ),
  mainPanel(uiOutput("documentation"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  tmp <- tempfile()
  onSessionEnded(function(){ unlink(tmp) })

  RdDatabase <- reactive({
    Rd_db(input$package)
  })

  output$choose_topic <- renderUI({
    selectInput("topic", "select topic", sub(".Rd", "", names(RdDatabase())))
  })

  output$documentation <- renderUI({
    rdfile <- paste0(input$topic, ".Rd")
    req(rdfile %in% names(RdDatabase()))
    Rd2HTML(RdDatabase()[[rdfile]], tmp, no_links = TRUE, package = input$package)
    includeHTML(tmp)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```